# is this bulletproof to get the url with alias

Tags: php, apache, http

I am working with apache mod_alias so using `HTTP_POST` doesn't give me the alias plus with HTTPS it's not there. The below line seems to work but could it fail? I understood `SERVER_NAME` needs to be configured on server but provided it is this ok?

```
$site_url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . "://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"];
```

Comment: What does $site_url return? print_r($_SERVER); ?

Comment: I get `http://localhost/myalias`

Comment: You could also leave out the scheme altogether, resulting in an URL starting with a double slash `//`. The resulting link will always use the same protocol as the current document your in.

Comment: If I don't put the scheme I'm getting some weirdness when I try for exmaple to put an img in html src it appends on top of $site_url the actual url as if nothing had been specified.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Example Output:

```
https://example.com/alias-no-extension?query=1
```