# Is $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] reliable?

Tags: php, url-parsing

I recently was seeking a way to properly determine protocol, under which url request was supplied to the server.

I watched through [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and though [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/$_SERVER) superglobal variable, and found this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

print_r($_SERVER);
```

Output:

> [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http

However, I was unable to find it on [*php.net*](http://php.net/$_SERVER) or Google. Though, I was able to find [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608952/is-this-bulletproof-to-get-the-url-with-alias) question. **Q#1:** If `$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']` wasn't documented, then it is probably unreliable, or it can be trusted?

I'am using `VC9 PHP 5.4.14 TS` under windows for development. But my production is under ubuntu. **Q#2:** Is this property also availible under ubuntu linux too?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is hard to prove that it is reliable, but it is easy to prove that it is not reliable (if only I could provide a case which it does not work). And I can prove that it is unreliable because it does not work with **IIS 7.0 + PHP 5.3**

Comment: Thanks. My production with `PHP 5.4.17` doesn't show it either.

Comment: Zend Server CE on Windows doesn't either!

Comment: Just to let google know: it's also missing on `lighttpd` with `PHP 5.5.9`.

Comment: It also does not work with Apache 2.2, in its "default" configuration.

Comment: and doesn't seem to be possible to set it to https when behind reverse proxy (with apache 2.4 as backend)

Answer (score 61):

The `REQUEST_SCHEME` environment variable is documented on the [Apache mod_rewrite page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). However, it didn't become available until Apache 2.4.

I only have Apache 2.2 so I created an environment variable. I added the following to the top of my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Set REQUEST_SCHEME (standard environment variable in Apache 2.4)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:http]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:https]
```

Now I can use

- `%{ENV:REQUEST_SCHEME}` in other rewrite conditions and rules
- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']` in my PHP code

I don't have to do extra messy conditional checks everywhere, and my PHP code is forward compatible. When Apache is upgraded, I can change my .htaccess file.

I don't know how you'd apply this to a Windows environment. This is probably not a good solution for distributed code, but it works well for my needs.

Answer (score 27):

As this variable is not available in all web server versions, *it is not reliable testing only it*.
Instead, you can change your PHP code to test two more server environment variables, which can also indicate that https is being used, as below:

```
if ( (! empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] == 'https') ||
     (! empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ||
     (! empty($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '443') ) {
    $server_request_scheme = 'https';
} else {
    $server_request_scheme = 'http';
}
```

As remarked by toxalot, REQUEST_SCHEME is a native variable of Apache web server since its version 2.4. Apache 2.2 does not have it (see [Apache 2.2 server variables)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and Microsoft IIs 8.5 does not have it either (see [IIS 8.5 Server Variables)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables). Naturally, if a variable is not set by the server, PHP will not include it in its global array $_SERVER.

Fortunately, for compatibility with codes based exclusively on REQUEST_SCHEME checking, you can create this variable in Apache 2.2 editing *all* your host configuration files (httpd.conf, ssl.conf, 000-default.conf, vhosts.conf), adding the following lines:

```
# FOR HOSTS LISTENING AT PORT 80
SetEnvIf Request_Protocol ^HTTP/ REQUEST_SCHEME=http

# FOR HOSTS LISTENING AT PORT 443
SetEnvIf Request_Protocol ^HTTP/ REQUEST_SCHEME=https
```

The code above presume the use of one vhost for every protocol (a best practice in Apache - see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/303744/serve-http-port-80-and-https-port-443-on-same-virtualhost) and [that](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL)).

Comment: That doesn't seem a good idea to assume `$server_request_scheme = 'http'` when the `REQUEST_SCHEME` environment variable is not defined. Moreover, for the `SetEnvIf Request_Protocol`, this doesn't work on vhosts listening on both ports.

Comment: Hi @xhienne. About the PHP code: the idea behind it is not to force the definition of a  variable which exists naturally in a web server: instead, the purpose here is to fix a problem which may arise in a server where this environment variable does not exist! In this case, you have a defined request scheme, but the server does not inform it to you "explicitly" (I mean, with precise strings as "http" or "https"). The code, therefore, is merely a translator, when the information that you wants comes in another variable and in a different form.

Comment: Hi aldemarcalazans. Sorry, I guess that, because of its length, I have missed the other conditions in your if statement and only saw a test on REQUEST_SCHEME. Actually, your PHP code looks ok. If you don't mind, you could split that long condition over multiple lines. Thanks.

Comment: Done: condition splited.

Comment: using Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) and php_fpm behind a reverse proxy (https happens before reaching apache) I just could not change REQUEST_SCHEME to https - seems like something else is forcing it back to http (I can see it changes the order variables are displayed in `phpinfo()` but value stays http

Comment: Hi @Antony Gibbs. In this case, I guess you should test another variable: $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto

Comment: Hi @aldemarcalazans. I would recommend to test for `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'` that can be set via `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL $https;` (nginx) and `SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=on` (apache2) and never, never use totally unreliable REQUEST_SCHEME

Comment: Does not work, it just set `REDIRECT_REQUEST_SCHEME` to https, but `REQUEST_SCHEME` is still http value. Im using nginx which sets X-HTTPS=on and in apache `SetEnvIf X-HTTPS on REQUEST_SCHEME=https`

Answer (score 11):

I, too, couldn't find a reference to `REQUEST_SCHEME`, but if you're looking to determine whether a request was made by `http:` or `https:` then you can use `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`, which is set to a non-empty value if a request was made by `https:`. It's documented on the PHP site [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: In certain condition `$_SERvER['HTTPS']` gives non-empty value (`off`) that indicates that HTTPS was NOT used. More about it on the page linked in the answer.

Comment: @F-3000 Thanks for the note. It's very useful.

Comment: ```isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && 'on' === $_SERVER['HTTPS']``` seems to be the safest way to determine https://

Answer (score 5):

In new version Nginx, set by default `fastcgi_param REQUEST_SCHEME $scheme`.

Answer (score 4):

This value depends on your web-server. If you use nginx (v1.10), in file `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` you can see this following lines :

```
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme; 
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
```

Generally, this default values are sufficient.
But it is possible that it does not work, you can force this values in your vhost :

```
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     https; 
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              On;
```

If you use Apache, you can take a look toxalot's answer

Answer (score 3):

Its interesting to see how WordPress resolves this issue with its [is_ssl()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_ssl/) function which makes use of $_SERVER variable,

```
function is_ssl() {
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
        if ( 'on' == strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) {
            return true;
        }
    } elseif ( isset( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this and i think it's best way to get the current scheme

```php
    /**
     * Is Secure?
     * Determines if the application is accessed via an encrypted
     * (HTTPS) connection.
     *
     * @return  bool
     */
    public static function isSecure()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) !== 'off') {
            return true;
        } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) === 'https') {
            return true;
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FRONT_END_HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_FRONT_END_HTTPS']) !== 'off') {
            return true;
        } elseif (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && intval($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) === 443) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Define this function and check server ssl connection to get current scheme

```php
        $scheme = isSecure() ? 'https' : 'http';
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` contains something like `HTTP/1.1` which is unrelated to what you are comparing.

Comment: @cherouvim It returns the web server protocol with its version, we can detect url scheme by this way. What made you think this answer was irrelevant?

Comment: The server protocol can be `HTTP/1.0`, `HTTP/1.1`, `HTTP 2.0` etc. How is comparing it with the string `https` relevant?

Comment: @cherouvim yes and could be https ones... my previous answer worked with Apache web servers, but thank you for making me update this post, now i edited answer to a production ready code , its codeigniter implementation for checking secure connections.
In the above method all possibilities and web servers are considered and it looks very reliable. hope to be useful

Comment: You totally changed the code. You previously tried to deduct the scheme from the protocol version which is not doable.

Answer (score 2):

Enhancing toxalot's suggestion for CloudFlare users:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:http]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"https"'
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:https]
```

Comment: I should add that that header is JSON and technically they could add space after the colon and break the logic of that configuration, but of course I understand that Apache does not allow to parse JSON and Cloudflare staff are probably aware that people are doing string matches inside the JSON.. More about Cloudflare special headers: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-CloudFlare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-